# Formal notation when using the axiom of specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

The axiom of specification states formally that for every property $\varphi$ holds $\forall X\exists Y\forall x(x\in Y\longleftrightarrow x\in X\wedge\varphi(x))$. Since from the axiom of extensionality such a set $Y$ is unique we define $Y:=\{x\in X:\varphi(x)\}$.

Now, extending the definition I'd like to know the formal definitions in the next cases:

> 1.- When people write $X=\{x:\varphi(x)\}$.
>
> 2.- Given any arbitrary object, let's say a function $f$, then the set $X=\{f(x):x\in Dom(f)\}$, or for example $X=\{\int_{a}^{b}: 0\leq
> > a\leq b\leq 1\}$, etc.

**Edit**: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly but what I'm looking for is some general definition to the cases given above, if there are some. I'm going to try giving my interpretation:

> 1.- I guess that this notations correspond to the case $\exists Y \forall x(\varphi(x)\longrightarrow x\in Y)$. If this holds then we
>   can have $\{x:\varphi(x)\}:=\{x\in Y:\varphi(x)\}$.
>
> 2.- I guess this case corresponds to some simplification like for example $\{f(x):x\in Dom(f)\}:=\{y:\exists x(x\in Dom(f)\wedge y=f(x))\}$ in the first case. In the second case it can be  $\{\int_{a}^{b}: 0\leq a\leq b\leq 1\}:=\{y:\exists a\exists b(y=\int_{a}^{b}\wedge $ 
>   $ 0 \leq a\leq b\leq 1)\}$.

**Note**: In the first case I think we have to prove that $Y$ is unique. In the second case I don't even know how to make the general statement to include all the cases that are similar to these examples I have specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities for $X=\{x:\varphi(x)\}$. This may be defining a proper class; in $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ it’s an informal definition, but there are axiomatizations of set theory that allow proper classes. Alternatively, the context may show that $X$ is really $\{x\in y:\varphi(x)\}$ for some $y$, and the notation $\{x:\varphi(x)\}$ is just a bit of sloppiness. **Added:** In the latter case you don’t have to prove uniqueness of $y$; you just have to prove that there **is** a set $y$ that contains all $x$ with the property $\varphi$. In practice this will usually be fairly obvious.

$X=\{f(x):x\in\operatorname{dom}f\}$ is readable shorthand for a perfectly straightforward instance of comprehension (specification). The function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs $\langle x,y\rangle=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. The sets $\{x\}$ and $\{x,y\}$ are then elements of $\bigcup f$, and $x$ and $y$ themselves are elements of $\bigcup\bigcup f$. Thus, $\operatorname{dom}f\subseteq\bigcup\bigcup f$. In fact,

$$\operatorname{dom}f=\left\{x\in\bigcup\bigcup f:\exists y\in\bigcup\bigcup f\Big(\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\in f\Big)\right\}\;.$$

using this abbreviation, we can then write

$$X=\left\{y\in\bigcup\bigcup f:\exists x\in\operatorname{dom}f\Big(\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\in f\Big)\right\}\;.$$

However, we don’t need $\operatorname{dom}f$ to describe $X$: $X$ is simply the range of $f$, so we can describe it directly as

$$X=\left\{y\in\bigcup\bigcup f:\exists x\in\bigcup\bigcup f\Big(\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\in f\Big)\right\}\;.$$

**Added:** It’s not clear just what class of definitions you have in mind here. If it’s as broad as the two examples suggest, I don’t think that you **can** make a general statement that both covers all such examples and is specific enough to be useful.

Comment: As always thank you so much for giving answer to my questions. I have edited my post. Could you please check out on my explanation.

Comment: Hooray! We got another one to the sans serif side of the notation!

Comment: @Asaf: I’m still debating with myself whether the value of a special typeface outweighs the sheer ugliness.

Comment: It does. By a supercompact.

Comment: @Daniela: I added a bit to address your edits. I think that your second question, in the generality that you intended, is simply too broad to have a useful answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok. Thanks. I'll think obout it. It's just a little confusing but I think I understand your point.

Comment: @Daniela: You’re welcome. It’s good that you’re thinking about it: if you’re going to work with formal set-theoretic notions, it’s important to learn to recognize how more informal descriptions can in principle be translated into formal ones, though in practice there’s rarely any reason to do it (and it’s usually a royal pain).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott after thinking about this and how I would introduce this to someone new to set theory: would it be correct to say that we use *set builder notation* to define a set - whether that may be by listing its elements within the brackets or by a predicate $\{x\in y:\varphi(x)\}$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, with the understanding that a set can be defined without using this notation (e.g., *the set of real numbers strictly between $0$ and $1$*). If we have an explicit list of all of the elements, or a description of the form $\{x\in y:\varphi(x)\}$ for suitable $\varphi$, we have a genuine definition of a set. And the technical details hiding under *suitable* can certainly be deferred.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That makes sense! Following up with the example you gave, can we  define a set simply by using *words* as long as such a description is well-defined? Such as *the set of natural numbers that are even*.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, with the caveat that verbal descriptions run some risk of being ambiguous, thanks to the vagaries of natural language.